# How to get the sum of a specific user from two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have 2 tables:

Favorite:
userID
drinkName

History:
userID
drinkName

I want to get the sum of the total times a specific userID shows up in each table, and then then the total number of times userID shows up in both tables.

```
(SELECT COUNT(userID) AS totalDrinks FROM History
WHERE userID = 'sai') union 
(SELECT COUNT(userID) AS totalDrinks FROM Favorite
WHERE userID = 'sai')
```

So that code gets me the following output:

> totalDrinks
>
> 4
>
> 2

However I am trying to use the MySQL sum function and that's not adding the two things up though.
So I was wondering how I would rewrite my query to output 6?

Comment: But are you expecting 3 pieces of output (one for each table and then the sum both) or only the sum of both tables?

Comment: i just need the output of 6 separately. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UNION` approach was almost there. You will have to `SUM` the result of both queries:

```
SELECT SUM(totalDrings) totalDrings FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) totalDrinks FROM History
    WHERE userID = 'sai'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Favorite
    WHERE userID = 'sai'
) s
```

A few things to note. You should use `UNION ALL` otherwise if the `COUNT`s result in the same number then they will be added only once. Another thing is that you should not use an `INNER JOIN` in here as that will force the users to be present in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM(userID)as totalDrinks   FROM History h 
JOIN Favorite f ON h.userID=f.userID 
GROUP BY userID
WHERE userID = 'sai'
```